# Google scripts search single column and edit row based on result

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to make a script button that will iterate through all rows and simply subtract cell G from cell E if G has a numerical value in it, then clear cell G.

I am having issues with trying to get only column G to see if it contains a numerical value, normally column G will be blank

I have tried getting the range specified but it is not sticking to the G column and is going everywhere. And I think I am probably not going about this the proper way. Right now I am just trying to get the cells with data in the G column to highlight so I know if I am even searching the right cells

```
function calculate() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var rangeData = sheet.getDataRange();
var lastColumn = rangeData.getLastColumn();
var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();
var searchRange = sheet.getRange("G1:G300");
var substring = "";

  // Get array of values in the search Range
  var rangeValues = searchRange.getValues();
  // Loop through array and if condition met, add relevant
  // background color.
  for ( i = 0; i < lastColumn - 1; i++){
    for ( j = 0 ; j < lastRow - 1; j++){

      if(rangeValues[j][i] != ""){
        sheet.getRange(j+1,i+7).setBackground("#cc4125");
      }; 
    };
  };
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this -

```
function calculate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sValues = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // E = 5, in array it is 4
  // G = 7, in array it is 6

  // Loop through array and if condition met, do stuff
  sValues.forEach(function(row, i) {
    if (row[6] != '') {
      row[4] = row[4] - row[6];
      row[6] = '';
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, 7).setBackground('#cc4125');
    }
  });

  sheet.getDataRange().setValues(sValues);
}
```

Comment: That did the math part, but it also removed all hyperlinks in the sheet, and any formulas too. The F column was calculating percentages and the C column had numerous hyperlinks, is there a way to limit it to just the E and G columns?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ra89fi, you gave me 99% of what I needed, here is the end result that worked

```
function calculate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sValues = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // E = 5, in array it is 4
  // G = 7, in array it is 6

  // Loop through array and if condition met, do stuff
  sValues.forEach(function(row, i) {
    if (row[6] != '') {
      row[4] = row[4] - row[6];
      row[6] = '';
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, 5).getCell(1,1).setValue(row[4]);
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, 7).getCell(1,1).setValue('');
    }
  });
}
```